# Discord.JS EmbedMessage with Collectors

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I'm working on a help menu that uses reactions for different sets of commands but I'm getting an error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Discord.MessagesEmbed is not a constructor`.  I'm unsure if this is due to another issue or if I am making a simple issue.  I'm assuming there's something else that isn't done correctly, but I'm open to suggestions, thanks in advance!

Edit: Error is on line 20

Update: Constructor error was solved, although I'm no longer receiving errors, so I'm assuming it's functional, just not for the intended purpose.

```
    exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    const Discord = require('discord.js');

      var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("help")
        .setColor("#d73a27")
        .setDescription("React to the following for different help sections: ")
        .addField("Moderation Commands", "React with ⚙️")
        .addField("Fun Commands", "React with ");
      message.channel.send(embed)
        .then(m => {
        m.react('⚙️');
        m.react('');

          const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '⚙️' && user.id === message.author.id;
          const collector = m.createReactionCollector(filter, { max: 600, time: 0 });

    collector.on('collect', () => {
      m.reactions.removeAll();
      var embed = new Discord.MessagesEmbed()
        .setColor("#d73a27")
        .setTitle('Fun Commands')
        .addField('☆  URBAN  ☆', 'Search a term on urban dictionary', true)
        .addField('☆  MC  ☆', 'Searches for a Minecraft profile', true)
        .addField('☆  POLL  ☆', 'Creates a yes or no poll', true);

          const filter2 = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
          const collector2 = m.createReactionCollector(filter2, { max: 600, time: 0 });

    collector2.on('collect', () => {
      m.reactions.removeAll();
      var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#d73a27")
        .setTitle('Moderation Commands')
        .addField('☆  BAN  ☆', 'Bans a user', true)
        .addField('☆  MUTE  ☆', 'Mute a user', true)
        .addField('☆  UNMUTE  ☆', 'Unmute a user', true)
        .addField('☆  SHRED  ☆', 'Deletes the last 100 messages', true)
        .addField('☆  NUKE  ☆', 'Repeatedly shreds', true);

      m.edit(embed);
      m.react('⬅️');

            const filter3 = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '⬅️' && user.id === message.author.id;
            const collector3 = m.createReactionCollector(filter3, { max: 600, time: 0 });

    collector3.on('collect', () => {
      m.reactions.removeAll();
      var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("help")
        .setColor("#d73a27")
        .setDescription("React to the following for different help sections: ")
        .addField("Moderation Commands", "React with ⚙️")
        .addField("Fun Commands", "React with ");
      m.edit(embed);
      m.react('⚙️');
      m.react('');
   })
  })
 })
})
}
```

Comment: Try Discord.RichEmbed()

Comment: Same error code with that, I think in discord.js v12 they changed RichEmbed to MessageEmbed regardless

Comment: It's a typo. Your error says `Discord.MessagesEmbed` is not a constructer. That's "Messages" with an "s". It should just be "MessageEmbed"

Comment: `RichEmbed()` is v11, `MessageEmbed()` for current v12

Comment: @Lioness100 ah thank you, unfortunately now it doesn't log an error whatsoever and the reactions added initially are removed when I click on them

Comment: Please create a new question if you have a new issue. [Read more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296489/when-is-it-ok-to-extend-a-question-with-another-question-after-initial-answers?r=SearchResults)

Answer (score -1):

Typo, look here:

```
 collector.on('collect', () => {
  m.reactions.removeAll();
  var embed = new Discord.MessagesEmbed()
    .setColor("#d73a27")
    .setTitle('Fun Commands')
    .addField('☆  URBAN  ☆', 'Search a term on urban dictionary', true)
    .addField('☆  MC  ☆', 'Searches for a Minecraft profile', true)
    .addField('☆  POLL  ☆', 'Creates a yes or no poll', true);
```

if you look closely, `var embed = new Discord.MessagesEmbed()`
you have a "s" after the Message in MessageEmbed()

Just remove that "s" and you should be good!